# Close a webpage that was opened in the flutter app, not in the browser

Tags: flutter

[image]

Sometimes the user is stuck on some pages because there is no close button at the top. Can this button be shown or do I have to activate the opening of the link in the browser?

im using package:url_launcher

and my code is :

```
                                MaterialButton(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'تصويت',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.poll,
                                        size: 35,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    String urlprivsy =
                                        '${data.docs[index]['poll']}';

                                    if (await canLaunch(urlprivsy)) {
                                      await launch(
                                        urlprivsy,
                                        forceSafariVC: true,
                                        forceWebView: true,
                                        enableJavaScript: true,
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
```

Comment: Can You add your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly adding the webpage in a stateless widget. Add an appbar with back button then in the body of scaffold add webview.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading : IconButton(
      onPressed:(){
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      icon : Icon(Icons.arrow_back)
    )
  ),
  body: WebView(
  )
)
```